# Change the home page of the default web browser by java code

Tags: java

I want to change the default web browser home page by a java code. The default web browser is one of `Internet Explorer`, `Firefox` and `Chrome`.

Comment: **Hint** every browser have a configuration file, so if you can edit this file you can solve your problem :)

Comment: another idea you can use command line for example firefox http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5314/change-the-homepage-of-firefox

Comment: Whenever I see someone want to programmatically change the browser home page, I think "malware", especially when it's for multiple browsers.  This might be unfair, but I still think it.